# Can I program a MSP430553 IC using the TIVA C development board?

Tags: microcontroller, programming, msp430, launchpad

I have a few MSP430G2553 ICs. Can TIVA C board (EK-TM4C123GXL) used to program the ICs as I need to buy it for a online class I am about to take ????
If yes, please specify the method to be followed.

Comment: Which part of the Launchpad doesn't work? If you're lucky, the two SBW signals on J3 may still be good. You only need these two, plus 3V3 and ground, to program your MSP samples.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Your question is very broad and might not be suited to this site. Also, we discourage requests for purchasing recommendations or requests for link-only answers, as neither of these has lasting value. Please try to ask more specific questions.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I am not sure. It is not detected by the Energia IDE.It keeps on reporting an error that no device is connected. SO I am unable to upload any sketch to the ICs.

Comment: The cheapest option is getting another msp430 launchpad...

Comment: @Passerby That is why I wanted to know if TIVA C could be used since I will soon be getting one. If I could then I wouldn't be needing to buy the MSP430 launchpad. So, back to my question. Is it possible to program the ICs with the TIVA C ( EK-TM4C123GXL ) development board ???

Answer (score 1):

The TIVA C is an entirely different architecture from the MSP430, and as such it's programmer cannot be used to program an MSP430.

TI has a nice list of all official MSP430 Flash Emulation Tools (aka programmers+debuggers) on pg. 11 of their [MSP430 Hardware tools user's guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slau278). It shows very explicitly which launchpads and FETs support certain MSP430s. I highly recommend using this table to decide on your purchase.

If you don't care too much about whether the programmer is "official", a nice alternative is the [GoodFET](http://goodfet.sourceforge.net/), though it seems to be a little less plug and play.

Answer (score 0):

It cant "easily" be used to program the msp430.  Yes you could wire up the tiva board to an msp430 part and write some sofwtare to program the part using the serial/jtag interface.  but it would make no sense to do such a thing when you can just get one of the msp430 launchpad boards and use that as a general purpose msp430 programmer.

Comment: can you provide some resources or instructions on how to make the right connection ???? It would be very help full for me. I know i can just buy an MSP430 board, but I haven't for two reasons. (1)Curiosity to do learn the alternatives. (2)It ain't so cheap for me here.Especially after conversion into my local currency. Please provide some detailed instructions or link to where I can find them. thank you.

Comment: you can download the datasheets and other documentation from TI's website for free.

Comment: I tried but can't find any instruction or steps that could work. Can you please provide links to those resources. Thanks.